# Why it isnt possible to project images through wall?

Tags: optics

Why it isnt possible to project images through brick wall or solids?Any theories or explanation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to project image through wall?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/675490/)

Comment: Please do not ask duplicates or near-duplicates of questions.  You have also need to allow a reasonable time period to answer [your question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/675490/is-it-possible-to-project-image-through-wall), although duplicates are not allowed.